# Monk sorting with limit option

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to use limit and sort in monk api in the following manner:

```
db.user.find({ changesId : '1234' }, { limit :4 , sort : { name : 1 } }, function (err,res) {
```

});

The sorting doesn't seem to work in this case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The edit corrected the syntax. It was earlier wrong as pointed by @AlexAtNet . Just leaving in case anybody will be wondering what is the difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code is incorrect - `}` is missing. The correct one:

```
db.user.find({ changesId : '1234' },
    { limit : 4, sort : { name : 1 } }, // <-  here
    function (err,res) { });
```

Answer (score -1):

collection.find must be kept as simpler as possible, I prefer a much readable and cleaner way. Have a look

```
        query={limit : 4, sort : "'name'  'asc'"} ;

            collection.find(query,
        function(error,sortedVals){
            if(error)
                response.send(error)
            else{
                response.send(sortedVals);
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps.